# Angular 7 parameters

Tags: routes, angular7

I'm trying to take the parameters of a URL in Angular 7 and it's always giving me back null or undefined. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

[This is the .ts of my component button](https://i.gyazo.com/77b31e2c8d7ef547e2bc113b1d66645d.png)

[And this is my presentation component where I tried to get the parameters](https://i.gyazo.com/a76e366567ae04b5f67e36de8620ba5f.png)

This is a part of my button component where I passed the parameter, mics.name.

```
<button *ngFor="let mics of Microfono" class="dropdown-item beige text-center" type="button" [routerLink]="['/presentacion',mics.nombre]">{{mics.nombre}}</button>
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: are the parameters angular url ?

Answer (score 0):

try this assuming you are getting url params for angular url (not url encoded url)

```js
 
 import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
constructor(private router: Router){}
 param1:string;
 $probando: Subscription; 
 href: string;
 this.$probando = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
 console.log(params) //to see the keys
      this.param1 = params[key];
      this.routeInvoiceId = params[key];
    });
    
    //if you need the url and it is not an angular route import router
    
this.href = this._router.url;
```